Ethernet on HP Thunderbolt G4 dock not working
I've got a HP Thunderbolt G4 dock attached to my Elitebook 840 G10 which is running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (kernel 6.8.0-45-generic).
Up until recently, everything was working fine.
Suddenly the Ethernet port on the dock stopped working.
This has happened a few times.
Previously I was able to restore the Ethernet port by running
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:2b\:00.0/remove
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan

Now, however, when I do that ... this appears in the dmesg output:
[ 1083.974094] pci 0000:2b:00.0: [8086:5502] type 00 class 0x020000 PCIe Endpoint
[ 1083.974148] pci 0000:2b:00.0: BAR 0 [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff]
[ 1083.974206] pci 0000:2b:00.0: BAR 3 [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff]
[ 1083.974547] pci 0000:2b:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[ 1083.974973] pci 0000:2b:00.0: Adding to iommu group 23
[ 1083.975453] pci 0000:2b:00.0: BAR 0 [mem size 0x00100000]: can't assign; no space
[ 1083.975458] pci 0000:2b:00.0: BAR 0 [mem size 0x00100000]: failed to assign
[ 1083.975461] pci 0000:2b:00.0: BAR 3 [mem size 0x00004000]: can't assign; no space
[ 1083.975463] pci 0000:2b:00.0: BAR 3 [mem size 0x00004000]: failed to assign
[ 1083.975908] igc 0000:2b:00.0: PTM enabled, 4ns granularity
[ 1083.976320] igc: probe of 0000:2b:00.0 failed with error -5

I've also seen this in syslog ...
igc 0000:2b:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): PCIe link lost, device now detached

and this ...
igc: probe of 0000:2b:00.0 failed with error -13

I KNOW the ethernet on the dock works. When I attach my macbook to the dock the ethernet works fine.
Based on some forum posts elsewhere, I added "pcie_aspm=off pcie_port_pm=off" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference.
I know the dock supports linux. HP even states it here: https://support.hp.com/us-en/documen...504-6213991-16
As a workaround, I attached a USB c Ethernet adapter to the dock and that's working fine.
Any suggestions on where I can look to resolve this issue.

Solved my own problem.
Looks like the kernel modules got screwed up with the last update, so I reinstalled them using ...
sudo apt --reinstall install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)

... rebooted and the ethernet adapter started working again.
